# Running 2 async methods in sequence. 2nd method dependent on 1st method

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, async-await

I'm new with Typescript/JS and I'm coming from Java.
I am trying to solve a scenario wherein the 2nd method call is dependent on 1st method's return value.

I managed to create a `getCustomerNumber()` method that is able to return a string value instead of  `undefined` The 2nd method `getCustomerName()` needs the return value of `getCustomerNumber()` as argument for it to successfully return the customer name value.

I tried making both of them as `async` methods that returns a `Promise<string>` object. However, `getCustomerName()` fails to retrieve a customer number from `getCustomerNumber()`

```
private async getCustomerNumber(rorn : string): Promise<string> {
    const getCustNo = new Request();
    getCustNo.transaction = "GetCustNum"; 
    getCustNo.argument = rorn; 

    let customerNo;
    await Service.execute(getCustNo).then((response: IResponse) => {
    customerNo = response.items[0]["CustNum"];
    }).catch((response: IResponse) => {
        this.log.Error(response.errorMessage);
    });
        
    return customerNo;
}

private async getCustomerName(cuno: string)  : Promise<string> {
   const getCustName = new Request();
    getCustName.transaction = "GetCustName"; 
    getCustName.argument = cuno; 

    let customerName;
    await Service.execute(getCustName).then((response: IResponse) => {
    customerName = response.items[0]["CustName"];
    }).catch((response: IResponse) => {
        this.log.Error(response.errorMessage);
    });
        
    return customerName;

}

private async callMethodsAndSetLabelText() : Promise <void> {
    const orderNum = "123456";  
    const customerNumber = await this.getCustomerNumber(orderNum).trim());
    const customerName = await this.getCustomerName(customerNumber) ; //get customer name by number
    console.log(customerName);

    const labelElement = new LabelElement();
    labelElement.setText(customerName);
}
```

Calling the methods:

```
callMethodsAndSetLabelText()
```

Logging the customer name in `callMethodsAndSetLabelText()` results to `undefined`

```
console.log(customerName); //undefined
```

I don't know how to set it up in a way that will work for the 2nd method since it's dependent on the 1st method.

I'd appreciate any comments or suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: While you don't necessarily need the `then`/`catch` handler around `Service.execute(getCustName)`, this still should work. Are you sure that `response.items[0]["CustName"];` is defined? Can you `console.log()` it?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. If I remove entire `getCustomerName()` I'm able to retrieve value from `getCustomerNumber`. The `cuno` becomes blank or undefined within `getCustomerName()`

Comment: `await this.getCustomerNumber(orderNum).trim());` is a syntax error. What's your actual code?

Comment: Your `getCustomerNumber`  function will return (fulfill the promise with) `undefined` when there is an error that you "handle" by logging it.

Comment: Please check output of
`customerName = response.items[0]["CustName"];`
in `getCustomerName` api, it must be undefined or you must be getting some error due to which `customerName` is not getting set and since catch block might be getting executed hence `customerName` undefined

Comment: I am getting an error that `GetCustName` transaction request fails because `cuno` is blank. Therefore, response is not acquired